# team synchronize perspective in eclipse has no context menu on right click

Tags: eclipse, svn

I've installed Eclipse 3.5.1 with a new workspace - I added the SVN plugin and aptana and almost everything works fine.
When looking at the file browser in the "Team Perspective" I have no right click context menu that allows me to commit/update the files from SVN.

This worked in my old installation of eclipse and disappeared in the new version.

Any one has an idea what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too and it really sucks, anyway...

Looks like they're aware of this issue...
[link text](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/922-can-not-synchronyse-svn-with-team-synchronizing-perspective-anymore)

What I did was perform an update but using the nightly builds option in

- window
- preferences
- aptana
- updates
- nightly builds

More info here on updating to nightly build aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/faqs/updating-changing-or-uninstalling/change-update-type